# Amplify + Appsync - How do I convert a connection on a field into a connection with a GSI

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I currently have a schema like :

```
type RawData
@model
{
  id: ID!
  controller: Controller @connection(name: "RawDataController")
  createdAt: String!
  notes: String
}


type Controller
@model
{
  id: ID!
  controller: Controller @connection(name: "RawDataController")
  notes: String
}
```

This works but I now have so much RawData for each Controller that I end up pulling too much data which causes pagination issues. What I want to do is get all of the Controller's Raw Data for today. I want to change the @connection into a RawSensor ID and createdAt GSI.

I tried adding a @key
`@key (name: "ByControllerCollectedAt", fields: ["controller", "collectedAt"], queryField: "rawDataByCollectedAt")`

but I get an error :
Expected scalar and got Controller
An error occurred during the push operation: Expected scalar and got Controller.

So then I tried to create a key on the rawDataControllerId field which is created in DynamoDB underneath AppSync's abstraction and currently contains the relevant controller id.

You cannot specify a nonexistent field 'rawDataControllerId' in @key 'ByControllerCollectedAt' on type 'RawData'.

I'm completely stuck, can anybody tell me how I can turn my current connection into one with a sort key?